# Python - printing statistcs when program is forcefully closed (in terminal or otherwise)

Tags: python, stock

I'm writing a program in python that is supposed to run all day long and I want to gather statistics about what has been done when the program is closed. However, I can't find the correct python way to do this. I have tried a try-except block with global variables but when I force stop it in terminal nothing is printed.

To be more clear about the problem and its code, my program keeps running through a database of stocks prices and tries to find arbitrages between two different exchanges. I want to print how many checks and arbitrages were found while running. Simplified code for reference:

```
import list_of_stocks # my handmade list of stocks to be checked in the database
import arbitrage_tools # functions to check for arbitrage

#statistics
arbitrage_checks = 0
total_arbitrages = 0

def main():
    global arbitrage_checks
    global total_arbitrages
    list_of_stocks = default_list_of_stocks # setting the real list of stocks to be checked
    while True:
        for stock in list_of_stocks:
            arbitrage_checks += 1
            found_arbitrage = arbitrage_tools.check(stock) # checks stock prices in two exchanges and returns true or false
            if found_arbitrage:
                total_arbitrages += 1

if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        main()
    finally:
        print(f"Arbitrage checks: {arbitrage_checks}")
        print(f"Arbitrages found: {total_arbitrages}")
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't know what sort of forceful closure you're performing, but there may not actually be any way for your program to respond.

Comment: when I stop it using `Ctrl+C` on Linux then I see results. But if you get errors in C/C++ modules used by Python then it may not catch it. it can be safer to write results in file. In every loop open, write and close file - don't keep it open all time because on error it may close it without saving results. BTW: you could use module `logging` to write some information in file and later you can see when it crash and what values could make problem.